# Reading numbers from file and normalizing

Tags: linux, file, python-2.7, compiler-errors

Hello Everyone,
                      I want to load the data I have in a file, which looks like:

```
21.4,0.266667,0,0.966667,0.166667,0.966667,0.533333,0.1,...............
```

Now, I want to load this from the file and compute the normalization. I do:

```
f = open("Input.txt", "r") 
data = [line.strip() for line in f]
print data
norm = [float(i)/sum(data) for i in data]
print norm
```

But, I am getting the error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for float()
```

Although, I do the process directly into python 2.7 console in linux like,

```
a = [21.4,0.266667,0,0.966667,0.166667,0.966667,0.533333,0.1]
norm = [float(i)/sum(a) for i in a]
print norm
```

This works fine. I don't know what I am doing wrong. Please help me and I am new to programming. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the strings in the file to floats first.

```
data = []
with open('Input.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        data.extend([float(x) for x in line.split(',')])

norm = [x/sum(data) for x in data]
```

Comment: Yeah, I was working to that, but you got there first :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the inputs :)